# Create Gaussian distribution from random number generator output

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gaussian

I have a random number generator with output between -1 and +1 having a uniform distribution.

Is there a simple mathematical formula that would convert this into an estimated Gaussian distribution (around 0)?

Comment: If you can read Python, you could use the algorithm it uses. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py#L549

Answer (score 3):

Usually a random sample from $U(0;1)$ is used. If you have a random sample from $U(-1;1)$ you can consider the absolute values of your output as from a $U(0;1)$

Then use the [integral transform theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform)

Comment: Thanks. Me not being well versed in statistics, would you be willing to show how the resulting function looks?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). To be precise if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent samples from $U[-1,1]$, then

$$
Z_1 = \sqrt{-2\ln{|U_1|}} \cos(2\pi |U_2|), Z_2 = \sqrt{-2\ln{|U_1|}} \sin(2\pi |U_2|)
$$
are independent standard normal random variables. It is slightly easier than using the integral transform in the context of simulating normal distribution (as integral transform uses the normal CDF which is more cumbersome). But remember that integral transform is applicable for any distribution!!

Answer (score 1):

**Standard normal sample in R.** In R, the function `rnorm` (without extra parameters) gives numbers easily distinguished from a random sample from standard normal.

```
set.seed(2021)
z = rnorm(100)
```

The sample of 100 observations generated in this way
passes the Shapiro-Wilk normality test, with P-value above 5%.

```
shapiro.test(z)$p.val
[1] 0.2116184
```

A normal probability plot (QQ-plot) is very nearly linear (ignoring a few wobbles in the tails, as usual).

```
qqnorm(z); qqline(z, col="green")
```

[image]

**Standard normal sample from uniform data.** In R the function `runif` without extra parameters
gives uniformly generated pseudo-random numbers in $(0,1)$
Also, in R, the function `qnorm` provides an excellent
rational approximatin to the inverse of the standard normal CDF. So the following R code also gives numbers that
are difficult to distinguish from a random sample from
standard normal.

```
set.seed(312)
u = runif(100)
z = qnorm(u)
shapiro.test(z)$p.val
[1] 0.4793456
qqnorm(z); qqline(z, col="green")
```

[image]

**Using your pseudo-random numbers.** You say your pseudorandom numbers are uniformly
distributed in $(-1, 1).$ Such a sample of numbers
`v` can be generated in R as below. Then by taking
the absolute value as suggested by @tommik (+1)
and using `qnorm` as above, you can get a sample
that is not easy to distinguish from a random standard
normal sample.

```
set.seed(1212)
v = runif(100, -1, 1)
summary(v)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.97538 -0.55026 -0.09479 -0.07188  0.32183  0.98725 
u = abs(v)
summary(u)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01182 0.23112 0.44815 0.48566 0.77076 0.98725 
z = qnorm(u)
shapiro.test(z)$p.val
[1] 0.3778305
qqnorm(z); qqline(z, col="green")
```

[image]

*Notes:* In the early days of digital computers
the following method of converting pseudo-random numbers on $(0,1)$ that uses only simple arithmetic was used. Sum 12 variates $U_i \stackrel{indep}{\sim}\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ then subtract 6. Convergence by the CLT of a sum
of uniform distributions to normal is roughly
satisfactory. The results are nearly normal
but confined to $(-6,6).$

```
set.seed(12)
z = replicate(100, sum(runif(12))- 6)
shapiro.test(z)$p.val
[1] 0.2368584
```

For some years the Box-Muller method, suggested by @Suman (+1), was a standard method of generating standard normal deviates. However, double-precision arithmetic of the transcendental functions involved restrict the accuracy of the
resulting 'standard normal' deviates beyond about $\pm 7.$. This inaccuracy is difficult to detect by most methods.

The inverse CDF of standard normal cannot be
expressed directly but the rational approximation implemented in `qnorm` (due to Michael Wichura)
is accurate within double-precision arithmetic.